# Required to find p in the given probability mass function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

Given that the PMF is

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
  x&-1 & 0 & 1\\ \hline
 f(x)&p & 1-2p & p\\ \hline
 \end{array}

and $E(2^X) = \frac{2}{3}$, find p.

Now, I clearly can't use $\sum f(x) = 1$ so I used $\sum 2^x f(x) = \frac{2}{3}$ yielding
$2^{-1}p + 2^0(1-2p)+ 2^1p = \frac{2}{3}$ 
$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}p + 1-2p + 2p = \frac{2}{3}$

$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}p + 1 = \frac{2}{3}$

$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}p = \frac{-1}{3}$

$\Rightarrow p = \frac{-2}{3}$

But a negative answer doesn't make sense.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your solution. Could be some sloppy and careless problem-writing on the part of those who made up this exercise...

Comment: As pointed out by @zipirovich in the comment, the solution seems fine. The purpose of this comment is to address that 'a negative answer doesn't make sense'.

The [formal definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function#Formal_definition) of a probability mass function include that $f\left(x_i\right) > 0,\,\forall x_i$, and therefore, $p$ must be non-negative. However, the design of the problem may be flawed (as already pointed out).

Comment: $E(2^X)=\frac43$ would make more sense. In this case $p=\frac23$

Comment: @calculus $0\le p \le .5$

Comment: Note that the minimum of $E(2^X)$ is $1$, when $p=0$.  so $1\le E(2^X)\le 1.25$

Comment: @herbsteinberg Good point, I missed that. I didn´t get your message since my user name is cal**l**culus .